# Best way of python dbf querying datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, foxpro, dbf

I have tried to make a datetime query on a table inside a *.dbf file using python 2.7 and dbf module, but have been unsuccessfull.

This is my code:

```
import dbf
from datetime import datetime  
file = dbf.Table('databaseName.DBF')
db = file.open()
print db[0]['data']
print type(db[0]['data'])
```

**output:**
`2018-11-05
<type 'datetime.date'>`

Query:

```
dateToSearch = datetime.strptime('11/5/2018','%m/%d/%Y').date()
print dateToSearch
print type(dateToSearch)
try:
    db.query('select * where data == {0}'.format(dateToSearch))
except Exception as e:
    print e
    pass
try:
    index = db.create_index(lambda rec: rec.data)
except Exception as e:
    print e
    pass
```

**Output**

```
2018-11-05
<type 'datetime.date'>
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I'm not sure where do you say is an empty string? If I print dateToSearch the output is: 2018-11-05

Comment: Well somewhere it's trying to convert an empty string to an `int` and the string is empty, it's unclear whether it's failing at your query or when you try to create an index

Comment: Check that you dont have blank entries in any of the dateToSearch values.

Comment: @MEdwin in the second try when the index is created dateToSearch is not used and the same exception as in the first try is raised. This makes me think that the problem is not in dateToSearch value.